# How can I import photos with tags from f-spot to shotwell

Tags: shotwell, f-spot

I have about 5K Pictures with tags in F-Spot, So you can imagine the time I spent setting the tags.. And since f-spot will not be supported anymore by Ubuntu. As well as it has been replaced with Shotwell..

I wonder how can I import those pictures from F-Spot to shotwell ?

Comment: F-Spot will still be supported in 11.04: http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/natty/f-spot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shotwell can import F-Spot tags out of the box. Just choose the menu "import from F-Spot" (sorry, i don't know the english menu. It's the second menu-item).

It worked fine for me.

[image: Shotwell-Menu]

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 10.04 which has "Shotwell 0.5.0" and it doesn't have "import from F-Spot" feature.. I'll upgrade to 10.10 and see what will happen.. thanks anyway

Comment: Oh, i forgott to mention: I'm using 10.10 with shotwell 0.7.2

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using Ubuntu Lucid (10.04) there's no official package for the latest version of Shotwell, which is 0.9.

But there's a PPA which contains the packages required to get the latest version of Shotwell here:

- https://launchpad.net/~flexiondotorg/+archive/shotwell

This way you can import your photos from F-Spot and get all the other latest features and bugfixes.

PPA Usage Instructions:

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)